# OpenSSL [des-ede3-cbc] Decryption php

Tags: php, encryption, 3des, php-openssl, tripledes

i had to receive some data encrypted with 3DES with shared keys.
I'm using php7 and openssl_decrypt function, but I'm not able to recreate the result of the example of the documentation sent to me.

The OpenSSL command that create the data sent to me is the following:

```
openssl enc -des-ede3-cbc -base64 -K 17839778773fadde0066e4578710928988398877bb123789 -iv 00000000 -in D:/in.txt

Example:
string_encoded: 123456
data_to_decrypt: Ja79hWTRfBE=
```

I tried to decode "Ja79hWTRfBE=" with an online tool and I successfully obtain "123456".
(I used this tool: http://tripledes.online-domain-tools.com/ with input text  (hex) "25aefd8564d17c11", function: 3DES, mode: CBC, key (hex) 17839778773fadde0066e4578710928988398877bb123789, iv: 00000000 )

Below my php code:

```
$key = "17839778773fadde0066e4578710928988398877bb123789";
$decData = openssl_decrypt(base64_decode('Ja79hWTRfBE='), 'DES-EDE3-CBC', $key, 0, "00000000");
var_dump($decData);
```

var_dump return me bool(false).

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i can reproduce your goal with the following code:

```
<?php

$data = "123456";
$method = "DES-EDE3";
$key = "17839778773fadde0066e4578710928988398877bb123789";
$options = 0;

// transform the key from hex to string
$key = pack("H*", $key);

// encrypt
$enc = openssl_encrypt($data, $method, $key, $options);
// decrypt
$dec = openssl_decrypt($enc, $method, $key, $options);

echo "plain: ".$data." encrypted: ".$enc." decrypted: ".$dec;
```

- set data without base64
- use DES-EDE3 method
- transform your key (from hex to string)

Comment: Great. Thanks a lot @spinsch. You saved my day. Can you explain why you removed "CBC" from the method?
Can I assume that the two functions already use the base64_encode/decode functions when i pass the datas?

Comment: For who will read, my main error was to pass the key without convert it from hex to string. On the web there's a little bit of confusion. I read a lot of times that openssl_encrypt/decrypt accept the key in hex, but thanks to spinsch I have to assume that it's not true