# Encrypt using 3DES and PHP's openssl_encrypt()

Tags: php, php-openssl, 3des

I'm trying to implement 3DES in PHP (v7.4.6) using `openssl_encrypt()` but am having problems generating the correct ciphertext output. (I am aware that 3DES is insecure, but I must use it because the legacy system I'm connecting to requires it.)

Sample key:

`fa21b161b659afec7633e08ea5ef54aaddd8728f5d3f7b97`

Sample plaintext input:

```
9/3/2013 9:26:21 PM|100|john.smith@clubsoftpayments.com|John|Smith|1234.56
```

And expected ciphertext output:

`18E4719B4DC9C4E0581964C16B0077609B58717B465106A235AEC353467EC2A370AF97F3CFBB68B6E4005AF1178FE926418E49E55ECEFE794E28E8FC2DED4AFC077883B6D2517BD542F116408588B0B6`

The tripledes.online-domain-tools.com website correctly encodes the sample plaintext using "ECB (electronic codebook)" mode, resulting in the following ciphertext (shown as hex):

`18E4719B4DC9C4E0581964C16B0077609B58717B465106A235AEC353467EC2A370AF97F3CFBB68B6E4005AF1178FE926418E49E55ECEFE794E28E8FC2DED4AFC077883B6D2517BD5D00067BFA921ABC0`

Even though The last 8 bytes (`42F116408588B0B6`) differ from the expected ciphertext, both ciphertexts can be successfully decoded by the same website to the original plaintext:

Encode: http://tripledes.online-domain-tools.com/link/2b65dfdgf4MoJSND32/

Decode: http://tripledes.online-domain-tools.com/link/2b68348glGkJ0h3ejQ/

Attempting to encrypt the plaintext using PHP's `openssl_encrypt()`, I am calling it as follows:

```
$ciphertext_raw = openssl_encrypt(
    '9/3/2013 9:26:21 PM|100|john.smith@clubsoftpayments.com|John|Smith|1234.56', // plaintext data
    'des-ecb', // algorithm
    hex2bin('fa21b161b659afec7633e08ea5ef54aaddd8728f5d3f7b97'), // Key must be provided as plaintext, hence the call to hex2bin()
);
$ciphertext_hex = bin2hex($ciphertext_raw);
```

The resulting (hex encoded) ciphertext is:

`6e7267444579666f6b7338795334614347626949455a544347316d3768732f7730784b6552375945344e466f67463677737a6b786e463863506b79466c3941593956734579705939356c754d6b794a76347345424b302f47735a623972575543395a4f4f7857456e34744d3d`

**What is wrong with the arguments I'm passing to `openssl_encrypt()`?**

- Algorithm:

Since http://tripledes.online-domain-tools.com worked using "ECB (electronic codebook)" mode, I assume I should be using a cipher method that indicates both "des" and "ecb". `openssl_get_cipher_methods()` lists the following algorithms with "des" in their names:

```
des-cbc
des-cfb
des-cfb1
des-cfb8
des-ecb
des-ede
des-ede-cbc
des-ede-cfb
des-ede-ofb
des-ede3
des-ede3-cbc
des-ede3-cfb
des-ede3-cfb1
des-ede3-cfb8
des-ede3-ofb
des-ofb
desx-cbc
id-smime-alg-CMS3DESwrap
```

The only algorithm containing both "des" and "ecb" is "des-ecb".

- `options`:

I've tried every bitwise combination of `OPENSSL_RAW_DATA`, `OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING`, and `OPENSSL_NO_PADDING`, to no avail.

- Zero-padding the data:

I also tried adding two null bytes to the plaintext by appending `str_repeat("\x00", 2)` to make the length a multiple of the 8-byte block size. (Reference: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-encrypt.php#121545) This did not help.

- `iv` (Initialization Vector):

I'm not sure if I need an Initialization Vector since I didn't need to provide one to http://tripledes.online-domain-tools.com and it didn't return one to me when it encrypted the sample. Maybe I'm wrong?

- `tag`, `aad`, and `tag_length`:

As far as I can tell, none of these is applicable to 3DES so I am leaving them unset.

**How can I get `openssl_encrypt()` to encode the sample plaintext, using the sample key, to generate the desired ciphertext?**

I'm aware of [Cannot find the right 3DES cipher in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57112100/cannot-find-the-right-3des-cipher-in-php) and the [phpcrypt](https://github.com/gilfether/phpcrypt) project on GitHub. While the GitHub library works, I'm trying to figure out how to do this just with `openssl_encrypt()` if possible.

Comment: For anyone who might find it helpful, I've created a website that lets you specify the plaintext, key, ciphertext, and IV (optional) and it will provided the necessary PHP code to produce the desired ciphertext. https://www.kmoser.com/php-openssl-helper/

Answer (score 1):

The desired ciphertext (including end) is produced with the following PHP code:

```php
<?php
// Encryption
$ciphertext_raw = openssl_encrypt(
    '9/3/2013 9:26:21 PM|100|john.smith@clubsoftpayments.com|John|Smith|1234.56', 
    'des-ede3', // des-ede3-ecb
    hex2bin('fa21b161b659afec7633e08ea5ef54aaddd8728f5d3f7b97'), 
    OPENSSL_RAW_DATA
);
$ciphertext_hex = bin2hex($ciphertext_raw);
print($ciphertext_hex . PHP_EOL); // 18e4719b4dc9c4e0581964c16b0077609b58717b465106a235aec353467ec2a370af97f3cfbb68b6e4005af1178fe926418e49e55ecefe794e28e8fc2ded4afc077883b6d2517bd542f116408588b0b6

// Decryption
$decrypted = openssl_decrypt(
    $ciphertext_raw, 
    'des-ede3', // des-ede3-ecb
    hex2bin('fa21b161b659afec7633e08ea5ef54aaddd8728f5d3f7b97'), 
    OPENSSL_RAW_DATA
);
print($decrypted . PHP_EOL); // 9/3/2013 9:26:21 PM|100|john.smith@clubsoftpayments.com|John|Smith|1234.56
?>
```

Explanation:

- Since a 24 bytes key is applied, [Triple DES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_DES) (aka 3DES aka TDES) is used in the [3TDEA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_DES#Keying_options) or triple-length keys variant. OpenSSL refers to this variant as `des-ede3` (or `des-ede3-ecb`). The mode used is ECB. The `des-ecb` you apply, however, specifies [DES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Encryption_Standard) (in ECB mode). Even though Triple DES is based on DES, they are ultimately different algorithms.
- The 4th parameter in [`openssl_encrypt()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-encrypt.php) has the default value `0`, which means that the ciphertext is Base64 encoded during encryption. During decryption a Base64 decoded ciphertext is expected. Since the ciphertext in your example should not be Base64 encoded during encryption, the flag `OPENSSL_RAW_DATA` must be set.
- OpenSSL uses [PKCS#7 padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)#PKCS#5_and_PKCS#7) by default. This provides the *expected* end of the ciphertext. In contrast, the referenced web site applies [Zero padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)#Zero_padding), which results in the different end of the ciphertext.

Security:
 You have already pointed out that Triple DES is deprecated. Today's standard is AES. But [ECB is also insecure](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/20946/94390), because this mode does not use an IV. More secure is a mode with an IV (like [CBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Cipher_block_chaining_(CBC))), even better authenticated encryption (e.g. [GCM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois/Counter_Mode)).

Comment: Thank you for the code and detailed explanation! I suspected 'des-ecb' was the wrong variant (DES vs 3DES) but assumed that because it needed to be ECB, the variant would look like 'des-ecb3'.